# Git file list difference shortcut

Tags: git

I want to have a list of files that changed between current branch and master. To do this I need to run

```
git branch
```

to check which branch I'm in, and then run:

```
git diff --name-status master..<BRACH>
```

or run:

```
git diff --name-status master..$(git branch | grep '*' | sed -e 's/* //')
```

Is there a shortcut? `git diff --name-status` return list but between files yet to be commited and HEAD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions:

- try with `git diff --name-status master..HEAD`.
- create a bash alias (or a script)

For reference, in `man git`:

```
   HEAD
       indicates the head of the current branch.
```